# Optimization support for list in android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have small issue in arraylist android, let me tell you where i'm facing the issue.

I have a custom contact object, which holds the details about name, contact number and a unique ID. when i query the database i get the list and i will be storing in an ArrayList.

Here how i do

```
Arraylist<contact> ctlist = new Arraylist(contact);
ctlist = getitemfromDB();
```

in the next scenario, i do query and get some set of contact object based on certain condition. i get 
again contact list objects.

```
Arraylist<contact> newctlist = new Arraylist(contact);
newctlist = getitemfromDB(condition);
```

Now, if i pick any object from `newctlist` and search in `ctlist`, though the object is present in ctlist
compiler says object not found.

may i know what is wrong with the above way, if i search inside same list i.e if i pick an object from newctlist and search in it, i will get correct expected result.

what would be the problem.

Comment: "Now, if i pick any object from newctlist and search in ctlist, though the object is present in ctlist compiler says object not found." - that's because they are different objects representing the same information. You need to search by value, not reference.

Comment: also you can write `Arraylist<contact> ctlist = getitemfromDB();` in one line (the same for `newctlist`)

Comment: Oh,,, searching by value will be time consuming right.. i need to loop it... if i have 1000 contacts then wat to do?

Comment: @jlordo, i can write.. i get the filtered object from DB.. thats all... nothing difference in the above case

Comment: @MitchWheat, if i have 1000 contacts in array, then i have to run for loop for 1000 times by comparing value.. if the item is at 1000 th location.... so is this this the only technique?? apart from this any other alternate trick?

Comment: ..or you could just search the database. That's what they are designed for...

Comment: You are creating two Objects straight for the garbage collector. You could also use a different data structure like a Set or a Map.

Comment: @jlordo, ok ill see but one thing.. if i loop 1000 times, will it be a performance issue?? i believe yes... but what u think??? is it really required??

Comment: depends on what you do in the loop ;) If you can't use the database, i would rather use a Map (constant time) instead of a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told by Mitch Wheat, you are trying to compare two different objects. That's because List uses `equals` method to retrieve specific object. I think you didn't override it in your custom class.
Just implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on fields in your contact class.

In fact, you should try to always override `equals` and `hashCode` methods in classes where equality have a different meaning than just reference equality, e.g. beans. Please have a look [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29). Moreover, if you can, read chapter three from Josh Bloch's "Effective Java" which contains quality rules for those implementations (By the way, read the whole book, it's great).

Please note that there are librairies helping you implementing correctly those (Java7 `java.util.Objects`, Guava `Objects`, apache commons `EqualsBuilder` and `HashCodeBuilder`)

Be careful as those methods must have very precise mathematical property